# MongoDB wrapping mongo instance in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Working on a web application were I want a MongoDB singleton connection which can be reused in different modules. I to do this with the use of promises. I tried the following so far:

**Server.js**

```
module.exports = new Promise ((res, rej) => {
    let MongoDB;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/WIGAMEX',{poolSize: 30}, function(err, db) {
        // console.log(db);
        MongoDB = db;
    });

    if(MongoDB) {
        res(db);
    } 

    rej('no DB');
});
```

**Module 1**

```
const server = require('../server.js');

server.then( (db) => {console.log(db) });
```

It now says:

> TypeError: server.then is not a function

### Question:

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong

---

First you should include your returns into the connect callback.

```
module.exports = new Promise ((res, rej) => {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/WIGAMEX',{
      poolSize: 30,
    }, function(err, db) {
       if (err) {
        return rej(err);
       }

       return res(db);
    });
});
```

---

Second what you are returning is a Promise function, you will have to call it before to resolve it

```
const server = require('../server.js');

server()
  .then((db) => {
    console.log(db) 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     // treat error
  });
```